# How to create a dynamic array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

#### Description of this array:

- 10 dimensions, which represent 10 clusters.
- Each dimension's length is not fixed, and should be zero at first.
- After clustering, one coordinate (x,y) will be assigned to the corresponding cluster.

#### Example:

If (1,1) belongs to cluster 10, (2,2) belongs to cluster 9, and given a sequence of coordinates

`(1,1) (1,1) (1,1) (1,1) (1,1) (2,2)`

then `A(1)` to `A(8)` have no element while `A(9)` has 1 element with value `(2,2)` and `A(10)` has 5 elements with value `(1,1)`.

---

I tried to use cell array, and I "kind of" get one, here is my code.

```
A = cell(10,0) 
%create empty cell array
A(10,end+1) = {[1,1]} 
%assign (1,1) to cluster 10
```

So now `A` is:

[image: A]

Then suppose we have (2,2) and it should assigned to `A(9)`

```
A(9,end) = {[2,2]}
```

[image: A9]

Looks fine, but then if we assign (1,1) to `A(10)` again,

```
A(10,end) = {[1,1]}
```

[image: A3]

Then the length is still the same and `A(1)` to `A(8)` are not empty!

My question is, is there any other method that can help me to create a dynamic array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB, we'll often store multiple coordinates into a single array, such that `p(3,:)` is the 3rd point. [One of the reasons for this is that this is a much more efficient way of storing data, as each array has an overhead, and storing many points as individual arrays within a e.g. cell array therefore is very wasteful of memory.]

I would suggest you use that method to store coordinates within each cluster. For example:

```
A = cell(10,1); % 10 clusters, we won't change the size of A
A{10}(end+1,:) = [1,1]; 
A{9}(end+1,:) = [2,2];
A{10}(end+1,:) = [1,1];
```

Now we can see what is inside `A`:

```
>> A{1}
ans =
     []

>> A{9}
ans =
     2     2

>> A{10}
ans =
     1     1
     1     1
```

Note that `A{10}` is the contents of the cell (in this case a numeric array), whereas `A(10)` is a cell array with one cell.

`A{10}(1,:)` is the first coordinate in cluster 10. `size(A{10},1)` is the number of coordinates in cluster 10.

`A{10}(end+1,:) = [1,1]` is one way of appending an element. `end+1` is a non-existing location, meaning the array will be extended to accommodate the new data assigned there. An alternative method is `A{10} = [A{10} ; 1,1]`. I'm not sure if these two methods are equivalent or not. In the case of a vector, or when appending a column, then the `end+1` method is much more efficient, so I always recommend that method in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at matlab's **map** https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html

E.G. For your question:

```
A = containers.Map('KeyType','int32','ValueType','any');
A(9) = [2 2];

A(10) = [1 1;1 1;1 1;1 1;1 1];
```

Now **A(9)** has a vector with values (2,2) and A(10) has 10 row vectors with values (1,1).

You can retrieve the values the same way that you input the values:

```
>> A(9)

ans =

     2     2

>> A(10)

ans =

     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
```

Adding vectors to already defined keys:

```
>> A(9) = [A(9); 2 2];
>> A(9)

ans =

     2     2
     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a cell array of cells.

Use `repmat` to create a 10 x 1 array of empty cells:

```
A = repmat({{}},10,1);
```

In order to access nested cells you need to chain indexes:

```
A{10}(end+1) = {[1,1]};
A{9} (end+1) = {[2,2]};
A{10}(end+1) = {[1,1]};
```

Or more simple indexing:

```
A{10}{end+1} = [1,1];
A{9} {end+1} = [2,2];
A{10}{end+1} = [1,1];
```